# Is numbers countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I would like to know if you say: Too much numbers or so many numbers. Is numbers a countable or uncountable noun? and why?

Comment: What does looking in a dictionary tell you?

Comment: More to the point, how do you mean "are they countable"? You *just counted them* right now yourself. You said *numbers*. That's a plural. If it were uncountable, you'd have said "too much number". But you have not. You have answered your own question.

Answer (score 2):

> In 5 days, 2 people have together completed 8 tasks.

In the sentence above, there are exactly three numbers. You can count them. So, numbers are countable.

Therefor, "too much numbers" is wrong, and "so many numbers" is correct.

An example of something uncountable is sand. You can have too much sand in your shoes/in the playground/wherever, but you cannot *count* the amount of sand (although you can *weigh* it).

Comment: Rice comes into a grey area.

Comment: Maybe numbers are counted when referring to items that are usually discrete or for items that can be used in small quantities (even 1) as well as large quantities. Uncountable can refer to items which are used in multiples (mass nouns) so rice is usually used with 'much' even though its grains can be divided.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: grain is even worse. If you have too much grain, you have too many grains.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) discusses the reality/grammatical treatment conflict that does occur in some cases.  '[With] mass nouns such as "water" or "furniture",  only singular verb forms are used: the constituent matter is 'grammatically nondiscrete' (although it may [_water_] or may not [_furniture_] be etically nondiscrete). >> [quote tidied]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

too much numbers" is **INCORRECT**.

a QUIZ - http://esl.about.com/library/beginner/blmuchmanyquiz.htm

Comment: This does not answer the question. And “too much numbers" is **X**” does not make any sense in English.

Comment: I meant "too much numbers" is INCORRECT.